# Difficulty with a Prime Number program .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to write a program where if you input a number and click a button, the program will be able to determine if whether or not the number is a Prime Number (divisible by only 1 and itself).

When I input the number "5" (for example), the program states "Yes" it is a prime number. However, when I input "4", which is NOT a prime number, the program still states is a prime number.

I am unsure where I went wrong given the "If" statements and loop I wrote. My code is below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim iNum, iSum As Double
        Dim isPrime As Boolean = True
        iNum = Convert.ToInt32(tbxN.Text)
        For i = 2 To (iNum - 1) Step 1
            iSum = iNum Mod i
        Next
        If iSum = 0 Then
            isPrime = False
            lblAnswer.Text = "No"
        Else
            isPrime = True
            lblAnswer.Text = "Yes"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I believe it may be an issue with my "If" statement and that the program is only using the last value in the loop to make the prime number decision, however, I need it where if iSum is EVER 0, then it is NOT Prime. If iSum is NEVER 0, then it IS Prime.

How can I go about fixing this? Thank you!

Comment: You need to check inside the loop. You can stop early if you fin that it's not prime.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your logic, your current logic is overwriting the value of `iSum` and thus resulting in false result. Once your find that `iSum` is `0` , you should break your loop, otherwise the boolean variable `isPrime` would remain as false. *(I also changed the varaible `isPrime` to false at initialization)*

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim iNum, iSum As Double
    Dim isPrime As Boolean = False
    iNum = Convert.ToInt32(tbxN.Text)
    For i = 2 To (iNum - 1) Step 1
        iSum = iNum Mod i
        If (iSum = 0) Then
            isPrime = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If isPrime Then
        lblAnswer.Text = "Yes"
    Else
        lblAnswer.Text = "No"
    End If
End Sub
```

Also you can further optimized your code by checking it looping until `iNum / 2`, instead of `iNum - 1`, or even better *(as pointed out in comment)* is to check until Square root of that number:

```
For i = 2 To Math.Sqrt(iNum) Step 1
```

More about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

Comment: "Optimize by checking it looping until `iNum / 2`" You can go even further than that, and stop as soon as you reach the square root of `iNum`.

Comment: Checking 2 separately then starting at 3 step 2 will optimize even further.  Also I think you'll find using a do until i*i >= inum loop, will optimize even further, due to the overhead of Math.Sqrt.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm of detecting of whether or not a number is prime is incorrect:

```
For i = 2 To (iNum - 1) Step 1
    iSum = iNum Mod i
Next
If iSum = 0 Then
    isPrime = False
    ...
```

It assumes that if a number is non-prime, it will be divisible by *all* numbers in the range 2..N-1. The actual requirement for a non-prime number is to be divisible by *any* number in this range.

To implement this, check if `iNum Mod i` is zero, and stop the loop as soon as you see it. Set a flag saying "not a prime number" when `iNum Mod i` is zero. If your loop completes without hitting the above condition, then the number is prime.

Note that you do not have to check all numbers in the range 2..N-1: if you went through numbers from 2 to the square root of `N`, inclusive, and you did not find any divisors, you know that the number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

Also you dont need to sum anything, if you get p mod x == 0 in the range [2,sqrt(p)] that means p is not prime and stop the cicle and returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want something that works, all this is fine.  However if you want something more efficient a Sieve of Eratosthenes works really well.  Here's a function that generates a bitarray where each element whose index is prime is true the rest are false.  This is very efficient for one time use or even more efficient for repeated use.  Generating a 1,000,000 element array takes about 3 ms.

```
Dim Primes As BitArray
Primes = GeneratePrimes(1000000)
Dim IsPrime As Boolean = Primes(20)

Function GeneratePrimes(n As Integer) As BitArray
    Dim bits = New BitArray(n + 1, True)
    Dim max = CInt(Math.Sqrt(n))
    bits(0) = False
    bits(1) = False
    For i As Integer = 2 To max
        If bits(i) Then
            For j As Integer = i * i To n Step i
                bits(j) = False
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return bits
End Function
```

As you can see just the checking value of the element at the index returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

All those who mentioned square root are correct, 30%. you only have to check upto the square root + 1 (for good measure) but the real time saver is you only have to divide the number by all the PRIMES upto the square root + 1.

e.g.
to find out if 23 is prime you divide by the primes upto the square root + 1.

```
sqrt(23) = 4.79 so we go to > 5

23 mod 2 = 1,
23 mod 3 = 2, 
23 mod 5 = 3,
23 = prime
```

because none of the modulus calculations = 0